# VB sxript to make a questionaire form in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

Hello I just want to know on how to make a continuously questionnaire form in access that will update all the table once all the question have been filled. but before it reached end of the page, the user will be able to edited back and forth from forms to forms.

so it will be like this:

1. Total 30 forms
2. One form only update 1-3 fields in the table
3. Once the user finished with one form, the form will close and open another form.
4. The user will be able to back to previous form and edit it.
5. The buttons that it available only 2 buttons back arrow and next arrow(save data and move to another form and close current form)
6. The last form will save all the data.
7. When user finished all the question, the form will allows to be reopened from the first one and it will insert entirely new line of user data in table.

The one that i have done is

1. I create a form, with a box and tag, connected directly to the table, so it will updated in real time. so user can back and forth to edit it
2. "Next" button, using macro to close and open new form.
3. Final form using the folowing VB code to update the table:

   ```
   Private Sub Close_Click()

     CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Demographics(vid, cid, dobd, gend, heght, heght2,         wgt, wgt2, lschool, secschl, qualify, hqlify, army, abranch )" & _
     "VALUES('" & vid1 & "','" & cid1 & "','" & dobd1 & "','" & gend1 & "','" & heght1 &  "','" & heght21 & "','" & wgt1 & "','" & wgt21 & "','" & lschool & "','" & secschl1 & "','"  & qualify1 & "','" & hqilfy1 & "','" & army1 & "','" & abranch1 & "')"

     cmdClear_Click
     cmdClose_Click
   End Sub

   Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
     DoCmd.Close 
   End Sub

   Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
     vid1 = ""
     cid1 = ""
     dobd1 = ""
     gend1 = ""
     heght1 = ""
     heght21 = ""
     wgt1 = ""
     wgt21 = ""
     lschool1 = ""
     secschl = ""
     qualify = ""
     hqlify = ""
     army = ""
     abranch = ""

   End Sub


   Private Sub Form_Current()
   End Sub
   ```

---

Problem:

1. Final page script above wouldnt insert the data into the table at all.
2. It can insert data into table, if i indexed the column in the table, but it will end up messy if i did a lot of updates

My Questions:

1. Can anyone suggest me the correct VB script to do this continuously form activity, instead of update entire table per-form.
2. How do I create a form like in access 2003 on which i can create switchboard with login for user only, and special login access to the database only for administrator, so it will like an application. (im using Access 2010 .accdb file)

sorry for the long post, just want to make sure everything is clear, any answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

This is one of those cases where a bound form could prove to be handy.

You can use `INSERT INTO`, but you'd need to generate a different query for each form in order to avoid errors. If you set all of your forms to bind to the same table, though, the form fields can interact directly with the table without requiring a lot of code.

Try the following example, using 3 forms (though you can easily extend this out to 30 forms).

Each form has:

1. A hidden field, *ctlID* (bound to the table's ID field)
2. Any number of other fields, bound to matching fields in the table
3. A 'Next' button, *cmdNext* (or in the case of the last form, *cmdFinish*)

You can use the `WhereCondition` argument of `DoCmd.OpenForm` to keep referring to the same record across multiple forms.

Here's the code:

```
' Form1 code:
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    Dim iID As Long
    iID = Me.ctlID.Value

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ID = " & iID
End Sub

' Form2 code:
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    Dim iID As Long
    iID = Me.ctlID.Value

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3", , , "ID = " & iID
End Sub

' Form3 code:
Private Sub cmdFinish_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```